# Identifying if a value against 2 months in the past exists and display it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have data as follows:

```
  Col1    Col2              col3
    A      2020-01-08       25
    A      2020-01-11       26
    B      2020-01-06       32
    B      2020-01-08       45
```

I want to create another column(col 4) which will have the value for each category in col1 with the 2 months prior col-3 values as below:

```
   Col1    Col2             col3     col4
    A      2020-01-08       25        NaN
    A      2020-01-10       56        25
    A      2020-01-11       26        NaN
    B      2020-01-06       32        NaN
    B      2020-01-08       45        32
```

I tried pd.shift, but its not working If I have missing months in the data. Can anyone please help?

Comment: And where did the second row for A in the final output come from?

Comment: its the 2 mnths prior value in col 3 for A.

Answer (score 1):

Use np.where to conditionally identify groups in which consecutive difference are greater than or equal to 60 days

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].diff().dt.days.ge(60),df['col3'].shift(), np.nan)



    Col1       Col2  col3  col4
0    A 2020-08-01    25   NaN
1    A 2020-10-01    56  25.0
2    A 2020-11-01    26   NaN
3    B 2020-06-01    32   NaN
4    B 2020-08-01    45  32.0
```

Comment: its giving  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Comment: This works for me and the sample you provided. Happy yo help further if you have additional data.

Comment: I am sorrry..updated the question. The date format now is correct..it is YYYY-MM-DD. kindly help

Comment: Have you, coerced col2 to datetime. Can you try add `df['Col2 ']=pd.to_datetime(df['Col2 '])` before the given code and retry?

Comment: col2 was already datetime, except the format was yyyy-mm-dd. Coercing will work except for cases where its december or changing year , i.e row 1 2019-12-01 and row-2 is 2020-01-01.....any solution for this??